# How to Create Custom Helper Class in Magento2 then Call ProductRepository to get Product details

Tags: magento2, cart, product-page

Actually I need to  Create a Helper Class in Magento2 then Call ProductRepository in

> app/code/{vendor}/{module}/Helper/Data.php

to load Product details by sku and return   Product Details in cart page and display

> app/code/{vendor}/{module/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to create a Helper file

> Custom\Module\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Helper;

/**
 * Custom Helper for Load Products 
 */
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function loadMyProduct($sku)
    {
        return $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    }
}
?>
```

Then you can call this helper in your phtml file like below:

```
$customHelper = $this->helper('Custom\Module\Helper\Data');
$product = $customHelper->loadMyProduct($sku);
```

Comment: error shows in data.php

Comment: can you please mention here?

Comment: Thanks for your Support ,its Done

Comment: Welcome. :) and +1 for accepting as right answer.

Comment: your flag copied by me for profile

Comment: Sorry Jugal, but I have copy from here: https://www.google.com/search?q=indian+flag+gif&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=un0ERedIp83_vM%253A%252CrqIQtT9kldsVqM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kSOkYipyhfHPdrPmQ6NWrOfuhDZqA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcmIPZj4zjAhUZWX0KHWJPARQQ9QEwAXoECAYQBg#imgrc=Dv-U9BH3tWc_mM:&vet=1