# Issue with get product name in custom module

Tags: magento2

I try to display product name in custom module; I paste below code but get issue:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: _product in /home/fsgroup/domains/domainss.pl/public_html/app/code/My/Module/view/frontend/templates/vendor.phtml on line
```

code:

```
 <?php
    $vendorData = $block->getVendorData();
    $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
    if ($vendorData->getId()) {?>
        <div class="vendor-info">                                    <a class="product-item-link"
                                           href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
                                           title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>">
                                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                                        </a> <?= /* @noEscape */ __('od').' : ';?>
            <a href=<?= /* @noEscape */ $vendorData->getVendorShopUrl();?>><?= /* @noEscape */ $vendorData->getPublicName(); ?></a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

is issue here with variable:

```
$_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
```

I copy this from list.phtml and here working correct. What should I add more here?

Comment: $this->getProduct()->getName(); use like this, change "getProduct()" with your block function name which returns product

Answer (score 1):

In magento, everything you do in .phtml which require logic processing must be supplied from block class. You can know phtml's block class by:-

```
<?php echo get_class($block); ?>
```

In your case, you need $_product variable which is not defined, you need block's method like

```
...
public function getProduct()
{
   // Get product from register or repository or anyway

   return $this->registry->registry('product');
}
...
```

Then you will be able to access `$block->getProduct()` in phtml, then you will be able to get product name.

You can also use helper directly in phtml but I do not recommend using it.

```
$productHelper = $this->helper(\Vendor\Module\Helper\ProductHelper::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says $_product is undefined. Depending on where you are displaying this and your block class, your problem might likely be easily solved by adding this line before you define $_productNameStripped

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer it's the simpliest way to make what you need: [How to Create Custom Helper Class in Magento2 then Call ProductRepository to get Product details](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279887/how-to-create-custom-helper-class-in-magento2-then-call-productrepository-to-get)
The better way:
create a viewModel and che the product from registry product

Cheers